# Unique ID Code in Java

Tags: java, android

Hi I want you guys suggestion.

I want to create a 15 length key code form current time stamp. Code should contain small and capital characters with digits. Anyone can suggest how I can create a 15 length unique code from current time stamp? Using Java in servlet side.

Comment: What are your constraints?  Why not a GUID?

Comment: want something line BKtR3g5SxmN2  so on . . but should be generate using current time stamp

Comment: hi Simon if you can guide more about GUID ?

Comment: @aftab: *"if you can guide more about GUID ?"* I link to the Android UUID class documentation in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given your constraints, I'd probably [create a GUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html), append or prepend a timestamp, and transform it into the 15-letters format. GUIDs are 32 hexadecimal digits and so have 32^16 (1.20892582x10<sup>24</sup>) possible values (although not all of them are used). 15 characters with digits or upper or lower case English letters (so, 62 possible values per digit) gives you 15^62 (8.272905461x10<sup>72</sup>) — plenty of room. If you were okay adding `+` and `/` to your list of possible characters, you could use [Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) rather than doing it yourself.

Comment: Just for interest, GUIDS are statistically provable to be unique.  It *is* possible for two identical GUIDs to exist somewhere (and sometimes they are deliberately duplicated) but then the chances of them turning up in the same context, within the same system are so mind bogglingly small that you can ignore it.  It's similar to number of stars in the known universe having to make do with 1x10^14 GUIDs each (I can't remember the exact mantissa but it's of the right order).

Comment: @Simon: Yeah. They're not unique, they're unique *enough* for most purposes. And throw that additional timestamp in there...